# Hi am trying to get dat from a database and convert that to csv file and trying to upload it in sharepoint using sharepoint file add connector in mule

Tags: database, sharepoint, mulesoft, connector

I am trying to get data from a database and convert that to csv file and trying to upload it in sharepoint using sharepoint file add connector in mule. But am getting an **error** saying

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]
```

used authorization token to connect to sharepoint.

What should be written in content stream? I am sending csv data as payload

Comment: What is the flow? Share as **text XML**, not images. Share the full error from the logs, including all lines, also as **text**. Share an example payload to reproduce the issue. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.